# getting a response from $.post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm calling an ajax page using `$.post`.

```
$.post("ajaxpage.php", $("#theform").serialize());
```

How can I echo the response that the page returned? I tried saving to a var, but it's not giving me the response.

```
var resp = $.post("ajaxpage.php", $("#theform").serialize());
console.log(resp);
```

Comment: post is called asynchronously. If I had a nickel for every time this question was asked, I'd be able to afford to buy the entire [SE] network.

Comment: Have you even read the docs for it?

Comment: @zzzzbov And, you posted a utility for the same poster a few days ago.

Comment: @Dave Newton, do you have a link to that one? I can never seem to find them when I want to mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$.post("ajaxpage.php", $("#theform").serialize(), function(data, status, xhr) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post("ajaxpage.php", $("#theform").serialize(),function(data){
  $('#yourDivId').html(data);//data is what you recived from the server

});
```